# Responsive gallery thumbnails with text on hover

Tags: css, image, text, hover, alignment

I'm still going at my portfolio site and struggling to get minor details correct.

I've got the 9x9 responsive thumbnail images working, with a brightness change on hover, however, now I need to add in the title of each thumbnail selection.

I need the text to appear only on hover, and then be in the centre of each image (each text will be unique to the thumbnail, which is why some of my code looks unnecessarily long).

That is the goal of this gallery, but for now, I really am just trying to figure out how to get the text to move into the centre of each gallery image.

Failing this, I think I may try this with the image set as a background to each div, seems as though it's easier to align the text this way.

```
.thumb_title{
position: absolute;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

span{
text-align: center;
}
```

Above, I tried to use absolute positioning to take the text out of normal flow and then centre it to the div, although I'm pretty sure my css principles are incorrect here.

https://jsfiddle.net/205dmxdw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the it:

```
.imgContainer {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.thumb_title {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Another piece of the puzzle complete

Comment: Welcome. Good luck with the other pieces.

Comment: I changed the above so I could have a state change on the image, now I can't get the text to centre again without moving the entire light box element it's placed on:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zj0huc9h/ - sorry, hit enter thinking it would create a link break

Comment: ^^I'm trying to get the text right in the middle of the image, but you can see that when adjusting position, it moves the whole lit-up box

Comment: Create another layer (div with opacity), and center the span.text inside it, or you can add the text as attribute to the span.text, and center the text inside using a before with content: attr

Comment: Thanks, I just tried both and got the same result of the light box itself being re-positioned. I also tried using padding to bring just the text into the centre but this appears to be un-responsive.